# Check if value matches any regex in a list

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I have encountered some situations where I need to check if a value matches a regex in a list of regexes.  For instance, say I have a list of regexes which match filetypes:

```
['gundo', 'nerdtree', 'git*']
```

I need to find out if the filetype of the current file matches any of these regexes.  The way I would do it currently would look like this:

```
fun! IsIgnored()
    for ignored_ft in ignored_filetypes
        if &filetype =~ ignored_ft
            return 1
        endif
    endfor
    return 0
endfun
```

However, it would be nice if there was a shorter way of doing this.  Does vim have a function to do this, or do I just have to stick with the for loop?

Comment: There's a flaw in what you're trying to do. You're using globs, but treating them as regular expressions. As a regular expression, `git*` matches `gi`, `git`, `gitt`, etc. This is easily fixed by using `git.*` instead. Be careful not to use glob syntax, as is common when looking at file names and file types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did define [`lh#list#match_re()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib#lists-related-functions) (based on a loop for the purpose of finding which regex from a list is matched by a text).

However, in you case, why don't you just test `&ft =~ join(ignored_filetypes, '\|')` ?

Comment: Would this be faster than @Carpetsmoker's answer?

Comment: @EvergreenTree Probably, yes. But I suspect the difference will be minimal (probably unmeasurable) in most circumstances. Go for the solution you find the most readable.

Comment: I've no idea. carpetsmoker's trick with `index+map` would probably be faster than the loop (that I use on my library). However, the `join()` trick has good chances to be the faster one. Moreover, you can precompute the regex if the list of filetypes doesn't change.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the same:

```
fun! IsIgnored()
    return index(map(['gundo', 'nerdtree', 'git*'], '&filetype =~ v:val'), 1) > -1
endfun
```

We first map the expression `&filetype =~ v:val` to every entry in our array, this will return either `[0, 0, 0]` if there are no matches, or `[0, 1, 0]` if (for example) `nerdtree` matches.
We then use `index()` to check if the array that `map()` returns has an entry with a value of `1` (`index()` returns `-1` on no matches).